# jQuery tab - load part of a jsp when selecting the tab

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page and the page contents have been divided into different jQuery tabs.

One of my tabs (second tab), contains some tables for which many relatively expensive queries need to be run (java back end) to load the results.

However, these tables information is not something vital to be loaded every time the page is loaded (when someone needs them they click that specific tab to see what they need). This has got negative effects on the performance.

I was wondering if there is anyway that the content does not get loaded unless someone select / click the tab.

just to note I am not using AJAX for fetching my data.

Comment: Up to the last sentence, everything you describe suggests AJAX. You need to better explain the page architecture.

Comment: I am basically looking for a way to load and display the tab content when select / click. If AJAX can help, can you please tell me how, like calling an external jsp to be loaded on a tab, or other tricks.

Comment: You have three choices (a) load the page with all content ready-loaded, then switch panes on every tab click, (b) reload page with appropriate content on every tab click, or (c) selectively load (and optionally cache) content via AJAX on every tab click. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks I guess I am looking for option c. but I got problem loading content via AJAX. what I am doing is $("#X").load('/abc.jsp'); when click on tab (X is a div on that specific tab)

Comment: It's not possible to make judgment from such a small snippet of code. For sure `$("#X").load('/abc.jsp');` could work but only if the javascript, HTML and server-side script(s) all coordinate to the same common goal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **jQuery-ui Tabs plugin** that will allow you to create tabs and to load dynamically the content of each tab via Ajax. You can mix basic tab and ajax tab if you want.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/